# How to do file operations on salesforce b2c using system and custom jobs?

Tags: b2c

I want to export catalog as csv file on Jobs on Salesforce b2c to IMPEX file and then download this exported file to my local and remove it from IMPEX. What do I need to do with the code for this?

There are ready-made structures for catalog export, but it doesn't export as .csv, instead it exports as .xml. Then I need to add a custom parameter or function to the job so that I can run my own code, but I couldn't find it and I couldn't find how to download the file from IMPEX to my local with dw.io library. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the job framework better, a webinar is available: https://share.vidyard.com/watch/j29VTc9BbqpyH7kkrubW2k?

As for writing custom code to write a CSV file you can make use of the [CSVStreamWriter](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/scriptapi/html/api/class_dw_io_CSVStreamWriter.html).

```
var CSVStreamWriter = require('dw/io/CSVStreamWriter');
var File = require('dw/io/File');
var FileWriter = require('dw/io/FileWriter');

var csvFile = new File(destination);
fileWriter = new FileWriter(csvFile);
csvStreamWriter = new CSVStreamWriter(fileWriter, ',', '"');

// Generate CSV header row
csvStreamWriter.writeNext(['col', 'col2']);

// Generate CSV value row
csvStreamWriter.writeNext(['val', 'val2']);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try to direct catalog export using job that has existing functions with csv file to IMPEX folder instead of code. That's why, I just asked that if there was any way to export with csv.

Comment: @EminSonerTÜRK that can be done manually via Business Manager, however, it cannot be done natively via code. Therefore you'd have to either convert an XML export to CSV via an `XMLStreamReader` class processing the XML file and then use a `CSVStreamWriter` to write it back out as CSV or you can use a `ProductSearchModel` and `CSVStreamWriter` to generate it instead of XML as the data source.